# Citing format (autorname, year) (Elsevier)

Tags: formatting, citing, elsarticle

I am writing an elsevier paper. I have a problem with citation format:
 Using `\bibliographystyle{model2-names}\biboptions{authoryear}` or 
`\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}`, the refrence cited takes the format: "author (year)".

However, I need to have (author, year). How can I have this format?
Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just change all `\cite` and all `\citet` instructions to `\citep`.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Use `\citep` instead of `\cite`.

```
\documentclass[final, 5p, authoryear, twocolumn]{elsarticle}

% Create bibliography file for MWE
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}

    @book{luque2011,
        title={Handbook of photovoltaic science and engineering},
        author={Luque, Antonio and Hegedus, Steven},
        year={2011},
        publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
    }

    @inproceedings{sera2007,
        title={PV panel model based on datasheet values},
        author={Sera, Dezso and Teodorescu, Remus and Rodriguez, Pedro},
        booktitle={Industrial Electronics, 2007. ISIE 2007. IEEE International Symposium on},
        pages={2392--2396},
        year={2007},
        organization={IEEE}
    }

\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}


\begin{frontmatter}

    % Paper title
    \title{Development of a Generalized PV Model in MATLAB/Simulink Using Datasheet Values}

    % Author names and emails
    \author{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh} \ead{almotasem.aldaoudeye@ndsu.edu}

    % University address
    \address{North Dakota State University, Fargo, ND, 58102}



    \begin{abstract}

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules \cite on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    \end{abstract}



    \begin{keyword}

        % Keywords

    \end{keyword}


\end{frontmatter}



\section{Introduction}

Solar photovoltaics (PV) is one of the fastest growing power industries in the world thanks to its appealing merits, like the widespread accessibility to natural solar resources, high reliability, easy integration into buildings and structures, fast installation, modularity, and predictable annual output \citep{luque2011}. Between 2000 and 2013, total PV production has been experiencing annual growth rates between $40\%$ and $90\%$ reaching an overall increase of two orders of magnitude. By 2010, thin film PV technologies accounted for around $13\%$ of the PV market share. The values were distributed as follows: $5\%$ for a-Si, for $2\%$ Copper indium di-selenide/Copper indium gallium selenide (CIS/CIGS), and $6\%$ for Cadmium Telluride / Cadmium sulfide (CdTe/CdS). However, most of the efforts in modeling PV modules focus on modules on crystalline silicon (c-Si) cells technology which exhibits characteristics closer to ideal cells. Thus, it is necessary to develop generalized models suitable for different types of technologies.


Reference \citep{sera2007} derives expressions for several parameters given in a typical data sheet. Since the parameters of interest (series resistance, shunt resistance, and ideality factor) cannot be separated according to the given work, the authors devise an iterative algorithm to estimate these parameters. The algorithm keeps updating the shunt and series resistances, which adjusts the ideality factor accordingly. The process is repeated until all equations are satisfied.


% ===== The bibliography =====

%\bibliographystyle{elsart-num} % (For numbered Elsevier citations)
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} % (For authoryear Elsevier citations)

% The bibliography file
\bibliography{MWE}



\end{document}
```